# No Method Error // Helper // Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get my admin avatar from Gravatar using my email address. I copied some code from Ryan Bate's Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/244-gravatar

The application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(current_admin)
    if current_admin.avatar_url.present?
      current_admin.avatar_url
    else
      default_url = "#{root_url}images/guest.png"
      gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(current_admin.email.downcase)
      "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48&d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"
    end
  end
end
```

My Application controller has `helper :all`

My view has `<%= image_tag, avatar_url(current_admin), :class => "img-circle" %>` The error I get is **NoMethodError** and more specifically, `undefined method 'avatar_url' for #<Admin:0x007fc4ae804ee8>`

The `current_admin` is set by devise.

Comment: It seems that an admin does not have the attribute of avatar_url  You wouldn't have added the field avatar_url into the User / Admin model.

Comment: Have you already restart the development server after installing gravatar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through this RailsCast and it is very poor actually. At one point Ryan says just to add `avatar_url` to `User` without giving any hint where data for this field should come from.

So unfortunately you need to add this field by yourself by creating a rails migration if using ActiveRecord.

```
rails g migration AddAvatarUrlToUser avatar_url
```

But this is ONLY required if you want to allow users having their own non-gravatar images. If you want to stick with gravatar ones you can skip everything from section "Using Images From Other Sites With OmniAuth"

Comment: Makes a lot more sense! I was trying to figure out why the helper wasn't loading, but it was. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling your that the attribute `avatar_url` does not exists in your `Admin` model.

You should add it creating a rails migration if using ActiveRecord.